# mpi4py: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpi.1.dylib

Tags: python, python-import, mpi4py

I am trying to use python with mpi4py. However, when I run `from mpi4py import MPI` in a python environment, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so,  2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpi.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so
  Reason: image not found
```

In the specified path (`/usr/local/lib/`) I have what I think is a version of the required file called `libmpi.12.dylib`. I have looked at the [source code for mpi4py](https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py/blob/master/src/lib-mpi/compat/openmpi.h) and from what I can tell this file is valid, but for some reason mpi4py (MPI.so specifically) is still trying to use the .1. version.

The error message shown occurs whether I run using `mpirun`, `mpiexec`, or simply enter the import command in a terminal python session (the last one is how I generated the error message as copied here).

I would greatly appreciate any help on this. I have tried reinstalling and/or updating all the related packages and codes, but it has not solved the problem.

--- UPDATE ---
Out of desperation I tried renaming `libmpi.12.dylib` to `libmpi.1.dylib` and it worked, at least for now. I am still interested in a non-hack solution if anyone has one.

Comment: When you run your program, are you using MPI? That is, are you using the command `mpiexec -n# python myprogram.py ...`, or just `python myprogram.py ...`? To be clear, the former is correct when using MPI.

Comment: @Kevin, I have updated my question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem should be resolved now, however, I had the exact same problem one iteration later;

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/<proj>/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2):
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/open-mpi/lib/libmpi.12.dylib
    Referenced from: /Users/<proj>/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.cpython-35m-darwin.so
    Reason: image not found
```

My machine has a `libmpi.20.dylib`, but no `libmpi.12.dylib`, and although the source of mpi4py seems to check this, it did not work for me. My quick and dirty workaround was to make a symlink;

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/open-mpi/lib/libmpi.20.dylib /usr/local/opt/open-mpi/lib/libmpi.12.dylib
```

And it worked (at least, it was able to load the library). Do note that I'm actually not using MPI locally, I'm just including the libraries so the code is more or less portable for the cluster.

-frbl